# Recognize a red ball's position in an image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, html5-canvas

Say I have this image:

[image]

I'd like to recognize the position of the red ball in the image, I could measure the size of the ball(in pixel) in ahead.

I know that I could draw the image to a canvas, then I could get the pixel color data with `context.getImageData`, but then what should I do? which algorithm sould I use? I'm new to image processing, thanks a lot.

Comment: are we to assume, the color of the ball is unique (no other object of that color)?

Comment: @snies no, that's why the size of the ball is measured ahead

Comment: but we know the color or only the shape (and size) ?

Comment: @ yes. but the color of the ball maybe not pure red, though there's a threshold

Comment: what happens if, for example, there are two balls of the same color and which one of them isn't the ball? what if the other was just some red circle in the image?

Comment: @Joseph that's where the size of the ball come in

Comment: What is the threshold for the red color (out of 255)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's code dedicated to getting that ball position. The output position will logged to the console so have your JS console open! This code has some values in it that you can play with. I chose some that work for your image such as the rough diameter of the ball being 14 pixels and the threshold for each colour component.

I saved the image as "test.jpg" but you can change the code to the correct image path on line 11.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas width="800" height="600" id="testCanvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.onload = function () {
                console.log(getBallPosition(this));
            };
            img.src = 'test.jpg';

            function getBallPosition(img) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas'),
                    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    imageData,
                    width = img.width,
                    height = img.height,
                    pixelData,
                    pixelRedValue,
                    pixelGreenValue,
                    pixelBlueValue,
                    pixelAlphaValue,
                    pixelIndex,
                    redThreshold = 128,
                    greenThreshold = 40,
                    blueThreshold = 40,
                    alphaThreshold = 180,
                    circleDiameter = 14,
                    x, y,
                    count,
                    ballPosition,
                    closestBallCount = 0,
                    closestBallPosition;

                // Draw the image to the canvas
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                // Get the image data
                imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
                pixelData = imageData.data;

                // Find the ball!
                for (y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                    // Reset the pixel count
                    count = 0;

                    // Loop through the pixels on this line
                    for (x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                        // Set the pixel data starting point
                        pixelIndex = (y * width * 4) + (x * 4);

                        // Grab the red pixel value
                        pixelRedValue = pixelData[pixelIndex];
                        pixelGreenValue = pixelData[pixelIndex + 1];
                        pixelBlueValue = pixelData[pixelIndex + 2];
                        pixelAlphaValue = pixelData[pixelIndex + 3];

                        // Check if the value is within out red colour threshold
                        if (pixelRedValue >= redThreshold && pixelGreenValue <= greenThreshold && pixelBlueValue <= blueThreshold && pixelAlphaValue >= alphaThreshold) {
                            count++;
                        } else {
                            // We've found a pixel that isn't part of the red ball
                            // so now check if we found any red data
                            if (count === circleDiameter) {
                                // We've found our ball
                                return {
                                    x: x - Math.floor(circleDiameter / 2),
                                    y: y
                                };
                            } else {
                                // Any data we found was not our ball
                                if (count < circleDiameter && count > closestBallCount) {
                                    closestBallCount = count;
                                    closestBallPosition = {
                                        x: x - Math.floor(circleDiameter / 2),
                                        y: y
                                    };
                                }
                                count = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                return closestBallPosition;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i would go and cluster pixels of that color. For example, you could have a look up table where you store red (or in the range of a treshold) pixels (coordinates being the look up key) and an integer value being the cluster id whenever you encounter a pixel without any known red neighbours it starts a new cluster, all other red pixels get the cluster id of a red pixel they are the neighbour of. Depending of you algorithms kernel:

```
   A) XXX      B)  X
      XOX         XOX
      XXX          X
```

you might need to deal (case B) with a pixel connecting two prior not connected clusters. You would have to replace the cluster id of one of that clusters.

After that you have clusters of pixels. These you can analyse. In case of a round shape i would look for the median in x and y for each cluster and check if all the pixels of that cluster are in the radius.

This will fail if the red ball (or part of it) is in front of another red object. You would than need more complex algorithms.